# Wonder Plugin Carousel multiple playlist request from Youtube crashes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, carousel, youtube-data-api

I'm using Wonder Plugin Carousel Version 15.1. I'm trying to retrive playlists from my youtube channels which are more than 15.

I'm using carousel playlist integration and already display 2 channel's playlist on my webpage. However, when i try to add 3rd channel's playlist as seperate carousel like i did, it throws me error.

I checked console and see the error below:

```
2wonderplugincarousel.js:216 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.success (wonderplugincarousel.js:216)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at y (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)
```

Here is the wonderplugincarousel.js gettingplaylist parameter looks like

```
  getYouTubePlaylist: function(youtubeapikey, youtubeplaylistid, youtubeplaylistmaxresults, index, insert_index, onsuccess, instance, pagetoken) {
                var youtube_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=" + youtubeplaylistid + "&key=" + youtubeapikey;
                if (youtubeplaylistmaxresults)
                    if (youtubeplaylistmaxresults > 50)
                        youtube_url += "&maxResults=50";
                    else
                        youtube_url += "&maxResults=" + youtubeplaylistmaxresults;
                if (pagetoken)
                    youtube_url += "&pageToken=" + pagetoken;
                var all_done = true;
                $.getJSON(youtube_url, function(data) {
                    if (data && data.items) {
                        var original_item = $("li.amazingcarousel-item", instance.container).eq(index);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                            var video_id = data.items[i]["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"];
                            var thumbnail = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg";
                            var image = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg";
                            if (data.items[i]["snippet"]["thumbnails"] && data.items[i]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["maxres"])
                                image = data.items[i]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["maxres"]["url"];
                            var video = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id;
                            var title = data.items[i]["snippet"]["title"];
                            var description = data.items[i]["snippet"]["description"];
                            var new_item = original_item.clone();
                            new_item.removeAttr("data-youtubeapikey").removeAttr("data-youtubeplaylistid").removeAttr("data-youtubeplaylistmaxresults");
                            var item_html = new_item.html().replace(/data-srcyt=/g, "src=").replace(/__IMAGE__/g, image).replace(/__THUMBNAIL__/g, thumbnail).replace(/__VIDEO__/g, video).replace(/__TITLE__/g, title).replace(/__DESCRIPTION__/g, description);
                            new_item.html(item_html);
                            if (instance.options.lightboxobject && new_item.find("a").hasClass("wondercarousellightbox"))
                                new_item.find("a").each(function() {
                                    instance.options.lightboxobject.push(this);
                                    $(this).off("click").click(instance.options.lightboxobject.clickHandler)
                                });
                            $("li.amazingcarousel-item", instance.container).eq(insert_index).after(new_item);
                            insert_index++
                        }
                    }
                    if (data && data.nextPageToken && youtubeplaylistmaxresults && youtubeplaylistmaxresults > 50) {
                        all_done = false;
                        instance.getYouTubePlaylist(youtubeapikey, youtubeplaylistid, youtubeplaylistmaxresults - 50, index, insert_index, onsuccess, instance, data.nextPageToken)
                    }
                }).always(function() {
                    if (all_done) {
                        $("li.amazingcarousel-item", instance.container).eq(index).remove();
                        onsuccess(instance)
                    }
                })
            },
```

I've expected to show all my channel's playlists which may exceed more than 50 videos totally.

Is there any restriction from youtube to get results that have too much video ? I also tried to increase total video responds via plugin but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem which is may caused by quota usage of Youtube V3 Api.

Here is the link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota